# When onPaste inside contenteditable div, new lines are becoming empty divs like <div></div>, instead of <div><br></div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a contenteditable `div`, which seems to be a complete nightmare as an idea.

My problem is:

I'm intercepting paste events because I should allow plain/text only.

Any empty lines should be displayed as: `<div><br></div>`, but when you copy multiple lines and paste it around the contenteditable `div` you'll see in the console that some empty lines are being rendered as empty div's like `<div></div>`. (see the **Test Snippet** below in full screen to see the console). See pictures below.

I guess it has something to do with the break line character.

How can I prevent this from happening and make sure that if a line is empty, it becomes:

`<div><br></div>` ?

**NOTE:** I'm not using jQuery.

[image]

[image]

**Test Snippet**

```js
function handleInput() {
  console.log('DIV innerHTML: ');
  console.log(document.getElementById('root').innerHTML);
 }
 
function handlePaste(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // GET TEXT REPRESENTATION OF CLIBOARD DATA
  let text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  console.log('THIS IS BEING PASTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEED! ' + text);
  text = text.replace('\r\n','\n');
  text = text.replace('\r','\n');
  // INSERT TEXT MANUALLY
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
}
```

```css
#root {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Copy and paste multiple lines including empty ones</p>
<div id="root" contenteditable oninput="handleInput()" onpaste="handlePaste(event)">
  <div>123</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>123</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was infact with the way I was trying to replace the `\r` and `\n` characters. I also needed to replace it for two `\n` so that every line break receives a `<br>` in the contenteditable `div`

Here's how I solved it:

```
function onPaste(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // GET TEXT REPRESENTATION OF CLIBOARD DATA
    let text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    console.log('Text before replace:');
    console.log(text);
    console.log(text.split('\n'));
    text.split('\n').forEach((item)=>console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));

    text = text.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g,'\n\n');


    console.log('Text after replace:');
    console.log(text);
    console.log(text.split('\n'));
    text.split('\n').forEach((item)=>console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));

    // INSERT TEXT MANUALLY
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
  }
```

**SNIPPET WITH WORKING SOLUTION**

```js
function handleInput() {
  console.log('DIV innerHTML: ');
  console.log(document.getElementById('root').innerHTML);
 }
 
function handlePaste(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // GET TEXT REPRESENTATION OF CLIBOARD DATA
  let text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  
  text = text.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g,'\n\n');
  
  // INSERT TEXT MANUALLY
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
}
```

```css
#root {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Copy and paste multiple lines including empty ones</p>
<div id="root" contenteditable oninput="handleInput()" onpaste="handlePaste(event)">
  <div>123</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>123</div>
</div>
```